# Unknown interaction with mysql DB?

Tags: discord, discord.js

i write code, and if at first i sand command alse ok, but at the second time i have error
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
How i can fix it?

full code - https://imgur.com/a/CsFFltD

```
run: async (client, interaction, message, members) => {
    if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'set') {
        const channelsend = interaction.options.getChannel('channel')
        db.query(`SELECT * FROM logssystem WHERE guildid = ('${interaction.guild.id}')`, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result.length  <= 0) {
                const embedok = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`Система логирования включена в канале ${channelsend}.`)
                .setColor('Green')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({text: "Scared system", iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/mO4spcx.jpeg'})
                interaction.reply({embeds:[embedok], ephemeral: true})
                db.query(`INSERT INTO logssystem (guildId, logsChannel) VALUES ('${interaction.guild.id}', ${channelsend.id})`);
                console.log(`The guild ${interaction.guild.name} has enabled the logs system`)
            } else {
                const embedgived = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`Система логирования уже включена в канале ${channelsend}.`)
                .setColor('Orange')
          
      .setFooter({text: "Scared system", iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/mO4spcx.jpeg'})
                interaction.reply({embeds:[embedgived], ephemeral: true})
            }})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction` means that you took too long to respond and the interaction already expired.
To bypass this just put this at the beginning of the execution of the command:

```js
await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
```

and then use this instead of `#reply` to edit the already deferred reply later:

```js
interaction.editReply({ embeds: [...] });
```

*Note: You don't need to put `ephemeral: true` into the `#editReply` options as you already set it in the `#deferReply` options.*

Comment: it doesn't work((((
https://imgur.com/a/gqO06rN

Comment: yes because you put the interaction.deferReply directly before the editReply. I said you have to put it at the beginning of the command execution. And please put an `await` before the interaction.deferReply